# Not being redirected to specified landing pages

Tags: docusignapi

My sandbox is not redirecting to the landing pages I specify, but rather keep redirecting to the default DocuSign landing pages.

I am attempting to redirect to a site that is not on a www server, so it is just http://foo.com.

Can you please advise as to why I might be getting the failure and if it is indeed required that the hostname for the redirect be www?

Comment: What action are you taking before getting redirected?  Is this right after you sign during an embedded signing session?  Or is it when you close the window, decline to sign, or something else?

Comment: It is occurs after an embedded signing session, when i decline, or perform any action that I should be redirected for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to re-direct without any issues using the `http://foo.com` URL you have specified, so there must be something else going on with your code.  Have you seen the DocuSign API Walkthroughs located here?

```
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs
```

They demonstrate 9 common use-cases of the DocuSign API and if you look at the bottom 3 you'll see that they are all focused on **Embedding** functionality.  Using the 8th walkthrough, titled *Embedded Signing* I was able to get this working with the following requests:

1) **Create an Envelope from a Template with one embedded recipient**

```
{
"accountId": "221765",
"emailSubject": "DocuSign API Call - Embedded Signing",
"emailBlurb": "This comes from PHP",
"templateId": "9347C7AF-7EEE................",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "email": "fakeemail@gmail.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "clientUserId": "1001"
    }
],
"status": "sent"
}
```

2)  **Get The Embedded Signing View**

```
{
"returnUrl": "http://foo.com",
"authenticationMethod": "email",
"email": "fakeemail@gmail.com",
"userName": "John Doe",
"clientUserId": "1001"
}
```

If I sign the envelope or decline, cancel, etc. it sure enough re-directs me to http://foo.com.  You can set the clientUserId to whatever value you'd like but just remember to use the same value for that recipient when requesting the embedded signing (recipient) view in the second part.

Comment: I was setting the redirect from the branding page as show here: [link](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Account%20Branding.pdf). I will set it in my signature request.

Comment: Cool, if that worked for you can you accept my answer as solution?  Or at least vote it up for others to see?  Thanks, -Ergin